# Typhoeus Hydra run out of memory

Tags: ruby, hydra, typhoeus

I wrote a script that checks urls from file (using ruby gem Typhoeus). I don't know why when I run my code the memory usage grow. Usually after 10000 urls script crashes.
Is there any solution for it ? Thanks in advance for your help.
My code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'typhoeus'

def run file
  log = Logger.new('log')
  hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.new(:max_concurrency => 30)
  hydra.disable_memoization
  File.open(file).each do |url|
    begin
      request = Typhoeus::Request.new(url.strip, :method => :get, :follow_location => true)
      request.on_complete do |resp|
        check_website(url, resp.body)        
      end
      puts "queuing #{ url }"
      hydra.queue(request)
      request.destroy
    rescue Exception => e
      log.error e
    end
  end
  hydra.run
end
```

Comment: What does the `#check_website` do?

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to adapt your file processing - instead of reading a line from the file and immediately creating the request object, try processing them in batches (say 5000 at a time) and throttle your request rate / memory consumption.

Comment: I thought about it but I would rather want to do sth like `request.destroy`. (I added it to code but it doesn't work.)

Comment: Yeah... hydra has to actually have a copy of the request to perform the request, so even if you destroy the local request object, hydra will still hold onto a copy at least until hydra.run is called - there's simply no way to perform a request with a non-existent request.

Answer (score 0):

I've made improvement to my code, as you suggest I'm processing urls to hydra in batches.
It works with normal memory usage but I don't know why after about 1000 urls it just stop getting new ones. This is very strange, no errors, script is still running but it doesn't send/get new requests. My code:

```
def run file, concurrency
      log = Logger.new('log')
      log.info '*** Hydra started ***'
      queue = []
      File.open(file).each do |uri|
        queue << uri
          if queue.size == concurrency * 5
          hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.new(:max_concurrency => concurrency)
          hydra.disable_memoization
          queue.each do |url|
            request = Typhoeus::Request.new(url.strip, :method => :get, :follow_location => true, :max_redirections => 2, :timeout => 5000)
            request.on_complete do |resp|
            check_website(url, resp.body)
              puts "#{url} code: #{resp.code} curl_msg #{resp.curl_error_message}"
            end
            puts "queuing #{url}"
            hydra.queue(request)
          end
          puts 'hydra run'
          hydra.run
          queue = []
        end
        end
      log.info '*** Hydra finished work ***'
    end
```